# iOS Swift How To Use Gif File Inside My Project

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimage

In my app I need to use `.gif` and I did searched on it. Everyone asked to use `UIImage.gifImageWithName("funny")` or `UIImage.gifWithName("jeremy")` for adding `.gif` file. But I'm getting error on those `Type 'UIImage' has no member 'gifWithName'`. How to solve those Issues and How to use `.gif` in my app.

Comment: are you integrated the base class

Comment: You can use library for it. https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage This library helps you to load gif in application

Comment: iOS doesnt support GIF files so you have to use library for it. So if you do it without library then you have to load array of images as gif image

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Download UIImage+Gif.swift file from https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/tree/master/SwiftGifCommon and put into your project..

```
// An animated UIImage
let Gif = UIImage.gif(name: "jerry")

// A UIImageView with async loading
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.loadGif(name: "tom")
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

iOS won't support `.gif` images directly. You have to use latest version of third party library like **[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)**. The simplified solution is to use Webview.

Or else,
You can use [UIImageView+Extension](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gif%20image%20support%20for%20UIImage&oq=gif%20image%20support%20for%20UIImage&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6438j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score -1):

this code seems to help you!

```
@IBOutlet weak var whiteView: UIImageView!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GifView.loadGif(name: "funny")
    imagePicker.delegate = self
  }
```

Also, you have to add Controller for "loadGif" into your source and I think you can download on online.

Answer (score -3):

```
//
//  GifFunctions.swift
//  GifFunctions
//
//  Created by Ambu Sangoli on 11/12/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Ambu Sangoli. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import ImageIO
fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}




extension UIImage {

    public class func gifImageWithData(_ data: Data) -> UIImage? {
        guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
            print("image doesn't exist")
            return nil
        }

        return UIImage.animatedImageWithSource(source)
    }

    public class func gifImageWithURL(_ gifUrl:String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let bundleURL:URL = URL(string: gifUrl)
            else {
                print("image named \"\(gifUrl)\" doesn't exist")
                return nil
        }
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
            print("image named \"\(gifUrl)\" into NSData")
            return nil
        }

        return gifImageWithData(imageData)
    }

    public class func gifImageWithName(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main
            .url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif") else {
                print("SwiftGif: This image named \"\(name)\" does not exist")
                return nil
        }
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
            print("SwiftGif: Cannot turn image named \"\(name)\" into NSData")
            return nil
        }

        return gifImageWithData(imageData)
    }

    class func delayForImageAtIndex(_ index: Int, source: CGImageSource!) -> Double {
        var delay = 0.1

        let cfProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, index, nil)
        let gifProperties: CFDictionary = unsafeBitCast(
            CFDictionaryGetValue(cfProperties,
                Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary).toOpaque()),
            to: CFDictionary.self)

        var delayObject: AnyObject = unsafeBitCast(
            CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties,
                Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGIFUnclampedDelayTime).toOpaque()),
            to: AnyObject.self)
        if delayObject.doubleValue == 0 {
            delayObject = unsafeBitCast(CFDictionaryGetValue(gifProperties,
                Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime).toOpaque()), to: AnyObject.self)
        }

        delay = delayObject as! Double

        if delay < 0.1 {
            delay = 0.1
        }

        return delay
    }

    class func gcdForPair(_ a: Int?, _ b: Int?) -> Int {
        var a = a
        var b = b
        if b == nil || a == nil {
            if b != nil {
                return b!
            } else if a != nil {
                return a!
            } else {
                return 0
            }
        }

        if a < b {
            let c = a
            a = b
            b = c
        }

        var rest: Int
        while true {
            rest = a! % b!

            if rest == 0 {
                return b!
            } else {
                a = b
                b = rest
            }
        }
    }

    class func gcdForArray(_ array: Array<Int>) -> Int {
        if array.isEmpty {
            return 1
        }

        var gcd = array[0]

        for val in array {
            gcd = UIImage.gcdForPair(val, gcd)
        }

        return gcd
    }

    class func animatedImageWithSource(_ source: CGImageSource) -> UIImage? {
        let count = CGImageSourceGetCount(source)
        var images = [CGImage]()
        var delays = [Int]()

        for i in 0..<count {
            if let image = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, i, nil) {
                images.append(image)
            }

            let delaySeconds = UIImage.delayForImageAtIndex(Int(i),
                source: source)
            delays.append(Int(delaySeconds * 1000.0)) // Seconds to ms
        }

        let duration: Int = {
            var sum = 0

            for val: Int in delays {
                sum += val
            }

            return sum
        }()

        let gcd = gcdForArray(delays)
        var frames = [UIImage]()

        var frame: UIImage
        var frameCount: Int
        for i in 0..<count {
            frame = UIImage(cgImage: images[Int(i)])
            frameCount = Int(delays[Int(i)] / gcd)

            for _ in 0..<frameCount {
                frames.append(frame)
            }
        }

        let animation = UIImage.animatedImage(with: frames,
            duration: Double(duration) / 1000.0)

        return animation
    }
}
```

Save above code with any file name example GifFunctions.Swift add it to your project and use it like below

```
let gifToplay = UIImage.gifImageWithName("YourGifName")
YourImageView.image = (image: gifToplay)
```

Also you can use other methods.

Enjoy (y)